# Update Primary Key Column Name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code defines `Category` table in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories] 
(
    [CategoryID]             INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                   NVARCHAR(450) NULL,
    [SubCategoryName]        NVARCHAR(MAX) DEFAULT ('') NULL,
    [FurtherSubCategoryName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Categories] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CategoryID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_UniqueName] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Name] ASC)
);
```

I need to change `[CategoryID]` to `[ID]` i.e., change its name. How can this be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why?  `CategoryId` is a much better name for the column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Actually, I've a function in my code which is applied to many tables in the database and it requires Primary Key column name to be ID for all the tables.

Comment: I have to agree with @GordonLinoff - CategoryID is a much better name. In any other table, especially one with its own `ID` column, that is (approximately) the name that the column containing that data will receive. If it is named the same in *all* tables, then it is much easier to link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For versions SQL Server 2008 and above; you may execute the following stored procedure

```
exec sp_rename 'Categories.CategoryID', 'Id', 'COLUMN';
```

Reference [SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/rename-columns-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: `sp_rename` has been around a lot longer than SQL Server 2016 :-)

Comment: Thanks Dan. Updated the answer accordingly